# NSIS restrict folder installation

Tags: nsis

I have a NSIS installer I am working on that I need to be able to prevent installation to the "user error" folders (i.e. $SYSDIR, $WINDIR, $DESKTOP etc... )

I want them to be able to chose a installation path but just have the next button be disabled if they chose a location as listed above. I have searched everywhere and can't find an answer to this one.

I was trying to use this but I can still install to desktop:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE MyDirLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
...
Function MyDirLeave
  Push $0
    StrLen $0 $DESKTOP
    StrCpy $0 $INSTDIR $0
    StrCmp $0 $DESKTOP 0 proceed
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP|MB_OK \
        "Installation on DESKTOP is not allowed, choose another directory"
    Abort
    proceed:
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [.onVerifyInstDir](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#onverifyinstdir) callback function.

Edit:

```
Function .onVerifyInstDir
StrLen $0 $Desktop
StrCpy $0 $INSTDIR $0
StrCmp $0 $Desktop 0 PathGood
Abort
PathGood:
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I was trying to get the .onVerifyInstDir to work with this using push to set a check on selected directory and then checking it but it wasn't actively preventing installation to those folders...

Comment: This is exactly as I have it included, do I need to call abort in some other fashion?

Comment: Your push/pop is rather pointless (preserving $0 is not important here) and it will miss the pop when the abort path is taken but the code should still work (I don't have NSIS on this machine so I cannot really test right now) If you really want to grey out the button you need to use .onVerifyInstDir and not the MUI define

Comment: so do I leave out the MUI path's all together then? could you toss up a quick example and then I can expand on it as needed for the directories i need to oust

Comment: MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE is the normal leave function for a MUI page, ".onVerifyInstDir" (exact name) is a special directory page callback.

Comment: So do I need to have the MUI_PAGE in there at all? or just have a Function .onVerifyInstDir at the bottom with this code and it should work?

Comment: You need !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY since that adds the actual page, but you don't need the define

Comment: Where do I input the Function call then on the MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

Comment: .onVerifyInstDir does not depend on any other settings, just use the MUI macros normally...

Comment: The page I linked to tells you not to use MessageBox. Anyway, you are never going to block all attempts to install to desktop this way, you will not catch short paths, symlinks or just "c:\users\foobar\.\desktop"

Comment: Ok I will try this same code but cycle out Desktop for SYSDIR and see if that works for me in which case I will consider Desktop a wash